# Complex Inner Product Space Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, harmonic-analysis

I am working on this problem: In a complex inner product space 
      $$\langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int^{2\pi}_0 \|x+e^{it}y\|^2e^{it} \ dt.$$

My thought was to write out $y$ in a basis $y=\sum \alpha_ie_i$ giving $\langle x,y \rangle$ as a weighted sum of Fourier coefficients $\sum\alpha_i\hat{x}_i$ and establishing some relationship between this sum and the integral. Am I crazy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just compute. Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2\pi } \int^{2\pi}_0 \langle x+e^{it}y, x+e^{it}y\rangle e^{it} \ dt =&\ \frac{1}{2\pi } \int^{2\pi}_0 [\langle x, x\rangle e^{it}+ \langle x, y\rangle +\langle y, x\rangle e^{2it} + \langle y, y\rangle e^{it}] \ dt\\
=&\ \frac{1}{2\pi} \int^{2\pi}_0 \langle x, y\rangle\ dt = \langle x, y\rangle .
\end{align}

Note: I used the fact that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is conjugate linear in the first component and linear in the second component.